# Problema con llenado de colas en c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

tengo estos ciclos donde necesito que mis datos entren y salgan en forma de cola (primero en entrar, primero en salir) pero sólo logro que salgan con la estructura de una pila (último en entrar, primero en salir) ¿Alguien por favor podría corregirme o darme un consejo para lograr la estructura de la cola? Gracias!!!

```
    struct cola{
      char idpagina[8]="ID";
      char nompagina[100];
   };struct cola historial[5];
    int main(){

char opc;
//Llenado de la cola, con las paginas
strcpy(historial[0].nompagina,"www.bestheda.com");
strcpy(historial[1].nompagina,"www.ea.com");
strcpy(historial[2].nompagina,"www.hotmail.com");
strcpy(historial[3].nompagina,"www.playstation.com");
strcpy(historial[4].nompagina,"www.youtube.com");
int i, ireg=-1, reg[5], band=0;


    
        
                                 //Guardar los datos en forma de cola
                                
                                system("cls");
                                for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--) 
                                  {//imprimir 
                                    if(reg[i] == i){
                                        printf("\n%s %d \n %s", historial[i].idpagina,i+1,historial[i].nompagina,i+1);
                                    }//Fin if reg
                                  }//Fin for
                                  ireg--;   

                              
                                //Expulsar los datos en forma de cola
                                    for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
                                       {//imprimir 
                                            if(reg[i] == i)
                                            {
                                             printf("\n%s %d \n %s", historial[i].idpagina,i+1,historial[i].nompagina,i+1);
                                            }//Fin if reg
                                        }// for
                                    salida = getch();
                                    if((salida == '1') && (ireg == -1)){//El -1 el valor mínimo que toma al momento de decir
                                        printf("COLA VACÍA\n");
                                        getch();
                                        }
                                    else if((salida == '1') && (reg >= 0))
                                           {
                                            i++;
                                             system("cls");
                                             reg[ireg] = 9; //Rompa el for
                                             ireg++;//imprime al revez
                                            }
                            
                        }
```